# Top de Rham cohomology group for noncompact manifolds with boundary

Tags: smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, manifolds-with-boundary, de-rham-cohomology

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth, connected, oriented $m$-manifold with (empty or nonempty) boundary. I am aware that top de Rham cohomology group $H^m_{\mathrm{dR}}(M;\mathbb{R})$ is trivial for noncompact manifolds with empty boundary (cf. Lee: "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", theorem 17.32) and compact manifolds with nonempty boundary (cf. Weintraub: "Differential Forms", theorem 8.3.10 (b)). Also, $H^m_{\mathrm{dR}}(M;\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}$ for compact manifolds with with empty boundary (cf. Lee: "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", theorem 17.31, and Weintraub: "Differential Forms", theorem 8.3.10 (a)).

*Side note: top *compactly supported* de Rham cohomology group is trivial for noncompact manifolds with nonempty boundary (cf. Weintraub: "Differential Forms", theorem 8.4.8 (b)) and $H^m_{c-\mathrm{dR}}(M;\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}$ for noncompact manifolds with empty boundary (cf. Weintraub: "Differential Forms", theorem 8.4.8 (a)).

This leaves us with one remaining case: what is the top de Rham cohomology group for noncompact manifolds with nonempty boundary?

Comment: Trivial, but answering the implicit "why" question will depend on what you're already familiar with. Do you know a manifold with boundary is homotopy equivalent to its interior? Then this follows from what you already know. It would also follows from an appropriate version of Poincaré duality, but one usually doesn't set up relative cohomology in the de Rham context. You could also try adapting the direct proof for the boundaryless case (in case you've seen one) directly to the case with boundary.

Comment: Great, I was already suspecting that the answer should be "trivial", but could not see how to prove this... I like the first strategy that you propose -- if I understood correctly, homotopy preserves cohomology groups, manifold $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $M - \partial M$ and we are back at the noncompact case with empty boundary? By the way, regarding the other strategy you've mentioned, do you have a reference for the Poincaré duality appropriate in this case, noncompact with boundary?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. Look up "collar neighborhoods" to see how to get there. As far as Poincaré duality is concerned, ignore my previous comment; I had something slightly mixed up. There should be a version of Poincaré duality that could technically be applied, but I think it will require to work with singular cohomology and relative Borel-Moore homology. I haven't worked  this out myself and don't know a place where it has been, though it's no doubt possible, but it's safe to say that would take us way too far off-topic. The homotopy equivalence is the reasoning to go with.

Comment: OK, I understand, thank you for all the remarks! Please, just put your comment in an "answer", so that I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is any smooth manifold with boundary $\partial M$, then $M$ and $M\setminus\partial M$ are homotopy-equivalent and $M\setminus\partial M$ is a smooth manifold of the same dimension without boundary. This fact follows from the existence of what is known as collar neighborhoods, and is discussed in chapter 9 of Lee's book. Now, if $\partial M\neq\emptyset$, then $M\setminus\partial M$ is always non-compact (no additional assumption on $M$). Indeed, it is an open subset of $M$, but if it were compact, it would also be closed. Looking at a coordinate patch around any boundary point (here, non-emptiness is used), this yields an immediate contradiction. Since de Rham cohomology is a homotopy invariant and the top de Rham cohomology of a non-compact manifold without boundary vanishes, these observations imply that the top de Rham cohomology of any manifold with boundary vanishes. I stress that this argument works simultaneously for compact and non-compact manifolds with non-empty boundary.